# How to prevent elements from resizing themselves when there are multiple elements

Tags: css, pdf, coldfusion

I'm creating a report page for my application.  I'm exporting the report to a pdf document using the cfdocument tag.  My problem is, when I have a lot of pages in my report (see picture 2, a report with 245 pages) the divs that contain the reports, and the table at the top of the page shrink in size.  Their font is changed to a smaller size as well.

In picture 1 (a report with 95 pages), you can see the standard size for the report, and the size that I would like the divs/ tables to be by default.

I've changed just about every css style property I can think of, but no matter what I do, the elements automatically resize themselves when I have a lot of report data.  I even tried setting the min-length and max-length properties to the same number, hoping that this would make it impossible to resize, but it still shrinks with big reports.

Is there any way I can stop this from happening? I would like all my reports to be the same size (with the exception of the divs height which is different for each report, depending on its content.)

Any help is appreciated.
[image: picture1]
[image: picture2]

Comment: What version of ColdFusion?

Comment: I'm currently on version 9

Comment: They revamped the PDF engine in newer versions. You might have to go with that.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever runs into this very strange situation, the solution I found has to do with the div that is outputting tables at the top of the pdf file "From Tables:".  When more tables are present on the page, the rest of the pdf file shrinks down so that it can show all the tables.  Notice how the black bar covering the tables is much longer in picture 2.  The page is trying to show all of those tables on one line, and resizing the page to compensate.  I ended up outputting those tables 3 at a time on a new line for each set of 3 and it fixed my problem.  It still shrinks down slightly, but I'm assuming from James's comment that this has to do with Coldfusion 9, and the shrinking is negligible.  Best of luck to anyone who runs into this!